# Minecraft launcher won't launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

When I double click Minecraft, the cursor spins for a second then stops. I've reinstalled java and Minecraft. This all happened after I restored my laptop - Hp envy i7 8gb

Answer (score 7):

Attempt to launch it as with  administrator privileges. `right click > run as administrator`

If this doesn't work then delete your .minecraft folder. To find this press the `windows + r button` at the same time. This will bring up the run menu. In here type `℅appdata℅` and run it. The .minecraft folder should be at the top. Open it up and delete its contents. This will destroy your saved data ( although you can back that up). After this has been deleted reinstall minecraft and restart your computer.

To back up your saves for example simply just copy the world folder to your desktop and then add it back into your new installation when you want to access them again. DO IT NOW BISH

Comment: You should add a bit more on backing up the saved game files otherwise the poor guy might lose all his precious work.